# JQuery how to find the closest element that is neither a parent nor a child of the current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="calendar start">

        </div>     
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="calendar end">

        </div>     
    </div>    
</div>
```

We can assume that the `start` and `end` will always be on the same "level" of a branch from each other, and will at some point share a common parent.

Without knowledge of the exact HTML structure, how would I find `calendar end` from `calendar start`? What if they are nested further down?

**Edit**: For clarification. I want to start at `start`'s parent. Search all child elements for `end`. Then move to the next parent, and search all child elements...etc till I find `end`. I am wondering if this is possible with built in JQuery functions, without writing my own DOM traversal logic.

Comment: Define what you mean by "close"?  We would need a precise algorithmic definition of how you want to measure "closeness" in order to be able to answer your question because "closeness" is not any sort of standard so we don't know what exactly you mean by that.  Is a sibling element close?  It's not a parent or a child?  If there are no siblings, then what else is close?

Comment: Do you have any identity for the common parent?

Comment: The common parent could be anything, a form, a div, part of a nested list...etc

Comment: @jfriend00 I want to find the closest element that matches the criteria of having the `end` class. Starting at the parent of `start`, searching all child elements of that parent, then moving up to it's parent and searching all child elements...etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like below, But it is a costlier process.

```
 var parentWhichHasCalEnd = 
         $($(".calendar.start").parents()
                   .get().find(itm => $(itm).find(".calendar.end").length));
 var calEnd = $(".calendar.end", parentWhichHasCalEnd);
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dw5m0ob2/)

Explanation: We are selecting the `.start` element first, then we are retrieving its parent elements. After that we are converting that jquery object collection to an array of elements by using `.get()`. So that we could use `.find()`, an array function over it. Now inside of the callBack of `find` we are checking for `.end` over each parent element of `.start`, if a parent has `.end` then we would return that parent. Thats all.

You could get more understanding, if you read [.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/), [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: That works great! This was specifically for cases where I had two elements that needed to find each other, but they will always be close to each other, though there may be multiple pairs on a page. There shouldn't be more than a couple levels traversed so performance isn't much of an issue.

Could you perhaps expand your answer and explain what this is doing?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Do you expect something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dw5m0ob2/2/

Comment: I did not, but that is also helpful to see! Thanks. Could you demystify how this works so I or others can not only use it, but understand it as well? It would be very helpful as I am hesitant about using code I do not fully understand from answers I get on SO.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Sure. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if i got this right but have you tried children function in jquery

```
 $( ".calender" ).children( ".end" )
```

and for the parent you can use parent() function so you can first check the parent then the children or  vicversa

edit: 
if you dont know the exact structure the better way is to find the common parent and then search it's children :

```
 $( ".calender.start").closest('.common-parent').children('.calender.end');
```

closest function give the nearest parent

Comment: `.end` isn't a child of `.calender`, they're both classes of the same elements. And how would this find the specific `.end` that's closest to `.start`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery#next()` method from `.start` parent element

```
var startSelector = $('body > div > div:nth-child(3) > .start')
var endSelector = secondStart.parent().next().find('.end');
```

I think this method is faster rather than `jQuery#children()` method, but you can benchmark it if you want to

btw you may check my answer based on [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/runurorulo/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Performance aside. Will your code work for any number of nested levels like this? https://jsfiddle.net/dw5m0ob2/1/ This is what OP has asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.start').parent().parent().find('.end');
```

Comment: Have you read this from the question? _Without knowledge of the exact HTML structure, how would I find calendar end from calendar start? What if they are nested further down?_